# how to give a border frame around the contents of a page

Tags: border

[image]    \documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{report}

```
\newenvironment{packed_enum}{
\begin{enumerate}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}{\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Movies I need to watch}

Here is a short list of movies \marginpar{Flag A -- This note will appear in the margin.} I need to watch some day:

\begin{packed_enum}
   \item The Longest Day
   \item Kill Bill 1
   \item Kill Bill 2
   \item Pretty much every other movie created in the last 30 years. :)
\end{packed_enum}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What sort of frame?  Lines or clip art?  Every page or just part of text?

Comment: line --similar to ms_word has an option to give a page border of varying thickness

Comment: I like to use everypage and tikzpagenodes for that sort of thing.

Comment: If you want to frame individual boxes (like the marginpar) you should look at \fbox or tcolorbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run this twice.  It stores the tikzpicture locations in the aux file.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newenvironment{packed_enum}{
\begin{enumerate}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}{\end{enumerate}}

\newcommand{\myframe}{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[blue,thick] ($(current page text area.south west) + (-2pt,-2pt)$) rectangle
    ($(current page text area.north east) + (2pt,2pt)$);
\end{tikzpicture}}% easier to debug
\AddEverypageHook{\myframe}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Movies I need to watch}

Here is a short list of movies \marginpar{Flag A -- This note will appear in the margin.} I need to watch some day:

\begin{packed_enum}
   \item The Longest Day
   \item Kill Bill 1
   \item Kill Bill 2
   \item Pretty much every other movie created in the last 30 years. :)
\end{packed_enum}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) to tap into the shipout routine (`\AddToShipoutPictureFG` - the `F`ore`G`round of every page within the document), adding a `\frame` of desired width `\AtPageCenter`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic,lipsum}

\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
  \AtPageCenter{%
    \makebox[0pt]{\raisebox{-.5\height}{%
      \frame{%
        \rule{.9\paperwidth}{0pt}% Horizontal 0pt-width rule
        \rule{0pt}{.9\paperheight}% Vertical 0pt-width rule
      }
    }}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

`\makebox[0pt]` ensures the `\frame` is set horizontally in the middle of the page, while `\raisebox{-.5\height}` ensures the `\frame` is set vertically in the middle of the page.

Comment: how do i place an arrow thickness 1pt with angle 45deg--kindly guide

Comment: @jsbibra: You need to be more clear in your request of an arrow. If you want a thicker line, add `\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}`.